# Wildfly picketlink enable login via http

Tags: jboss, wildfly-8, picketlink

How can i enable login via http using picketlink ? now i am try to run quickstart picketlink angular https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-picketlink-quickstarts/. But for developer purpose i must have got option that picketlink allow get token via http.

Now when i try login i have got error :

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</body></html>
```

my login url rest/private/authc